# Sades K10 Keyboard Froze

Tags: usb, keyboard

I have a Sades K10 mechanical keyboard that recently froze itself when I plugged it into another computer. The other computer was fine as it was one of mine I was getting rid of. I plugged it in fast to boot it up, then I was done. It worked fine when plugged in, and before that, I then unplugged it and about 5 minutes later plugged it back into my main PC that was already turned on.

Immediately upon plugging it in the lights started flickering like something was wrong, instead of the usual flash on and off when it starts. I pressed a button and all the lights turned off and it wouldn't work after that. When I press a button, any button, the light under that button should flash, it doesn't. None of the keys work now, not even the num or caps locks, and every time I plug it in it flickers and upon the first key press of the function keys everything goes off.

I'm looking if someone knows a way to reset these? I've taken it apart and the keys are soldered into the board, and there are no reset switches or buttons on the board. Since it's USB I figured there might be a way to reset it programmatically somehow.

I've tried it on Linux, Mac and Windows machines, won't work on any of them. Consequently, my main machine is Linux, where it was plugged in for about 8 months without incident.

When I plug it in it's detected:

[image]

Here is a video of what happens when I plug it in:

[YouTube Video of Broken Keyboard](https://youtu.be/vniiG-NyJ6w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to "reset" your keyboard. Computers themselves don't typically modify keyboard software, in fact I don't believe there is very much [non-volatile memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_memory) on the keyboard (besides maybe some Boolean storing bits) so it would be strange if a software engineer programmed in logic that would stop your keyboard from doing it's most basic function, which is to type. In fact according to [this amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DLL41D6) of your keyboard it says

> No driver needed

I think you may have even run into an isolated case of [Electro-static discharge (ESD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge), although I will preface this statement with the fact that **ESD is typically ludicrously rare**. Your keyboard powers on, but non of the logic works in your keyboard. You described your keyboard not working after plugging it into two separate machines so this is the only explanation I can think of that would fit the description of behavior you have.

There is also supposed to be certain effects for the lighting of your keyboard so I think that's why the keyboard's lights turn off immediately and your fn key turns off the lights. A combination of fn and other keys is supposed to be able to change the light effects (which controls when keys are supposed to be on or off). If the part of the circuit dealing with logic is damaged, then the USB would only be able to transmit power to the keyboard LEDs and the logic of on or off would be completely messed up.

If ESD is the cause of your keyboard not working, this isn't a "resetable problem", it's done for. If you're worried about ESD in the future with your peripherals, I'd be willing to bet you'd never run into ESD again and it wouldn't really be worth trying to prevent such a rare incident from happening anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this actually makes sense now that you mention it. The keyboard itself has an aluminum "frame" so to speak, I've taken it apart since then, and then a plastic back. The last computer it worked on was the temporary one, I was using it at the time on the carpet on the floor! So it makes sense a static build up because of the lights, then when the PC powered off there was a discharge that coupled with the carpet and a possible "movement" of the keyboard on the carpet. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Keyboards can be reset to factory settings.  For example, the Corsair K55 with custom back-lighting can be reset to factory with "FN + F4" for 5 seconds.